# После изменения id jquery перестаёт на него реагировать

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

такая проблема: по клики на кнопку изменяется её id `$(this).attr("id","entrBtn");` и после этого функция которая должна реагировать на новый id не срабатывает `$("#entrBtn").click(function(){`, кто то сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `jQuery 1.7+` вы можете прикрепить обработчик событий к родительскому элементу (допустим `document`) с помощью `.on()` и передать селектор (в вашем случае новый `id`) в качестве аргумента.

> `.on(events, [selector], [data], handler)`
>
> **events** — тип(ы) обрабатываемых событий. Например "click", "resize" и.т.д.
>
> **selector** — селектор по которому будут фильтроваться
> элементы, лежащие внутри уже найденных. В итоге, обработчик будет
> срабатывать только в том случае, если событие «поднялось» от одного из
> отфильтрованных элементов.
>
> **data** — данные, передаваемые обработчику
> событий. В обработчике будут доступны в переменной event.data.
>
> **handler** — функция, которая будет установлена в качестве обработчика.

http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On - здесь хорошо все расписано об `on()`

Небольшой пример изменения `id` у кнопки:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#beginId', function() {
  $(this).attr('id','entrBtn')
  $(this).text(`#${$(this).attr('id')}`)
});

$(document).on('click', '#entrBtn',function() {
  $(this).attr('id','beginId')
  $(this).text(`#${$(this).attr('id')}`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="beginId">test button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

у вас `$("#entrBtn").click(function()` существовало до появления объекта `#entrBtn`? если так, то раз объекта не было, обработчик на этот объект не установился (ведь объекта не было)

так что после того как объект появился обработчик не срабатывал, потому что обработчика то не было :)

поэтому после замены `id` создавайте нужный обработчик или изначально вешайте обработчик на существующий родитель и уже в обработчике анализируйте `id` и если произошло нажатие на нужный объект - выполняйте требуемые действия